# Intellij Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I've got this valid bit of TypeScript (tested in the TS repl) but in IntelliJ 2017.2.5 it shows me the following:

[image]

Any idea how I could fix that? I've played around in the settings and this is what I currently have:

[image]

My project is currently using TypeScript 2.5.3 from package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was using this inside a *.vue file which was causing issues. Moving it to a standalone *.ts file resolved it.